# How to change the behavior of Cmd + D in RubyMine editor

Tags: intellij-idea, rubymine

I'm using macOS Mojave & RubyMine 2019.1 .

When I select multiple lines and press `Cmd + D`, it duplicates only where is selected, not duplicating the whole lines selected.
See the images below.

The first image is before pressing `Cmd + D` . The second one is after pressing.

I expected it works like the third image.

[image: 1st]
[image: 2nd]
[image: 3rd]

I could not find any configurations to fix this.
Is it impossible to make it work like the third image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **Duplicate Entire Lines** action instead:

[image: duplicate]